# ISO-8859-1 and HTML Entities

Tags: html, encoding, entity, character, iso-8859-1

I am working on a website, I don't know what has changed to cause this problem but in the last few days alot of the HTML Entity characters (&trade; &raquo; etc) have had junk characters (™ =â„¢ and » = Â») showing in their place. The pages use ISO-8859-1 encoding, In some places the problem can be fixed by forcing the browser to use UTF-8 encoding other times the UTF-8 encoding causes the HTML entites to be replaced by a "�". Any ideas as to why this might be happening and how to fix it. ISO-8859-1 should be able to correctly display html entities.

Comment: When you see this �, its, most of the time, because it's already in UTF-8 and reencoded in UTF-8 again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your editor is encoding the page as UTF-8 instead of ISO-8859-1 and has converted the entities to UTF-8. Check your editor's settings.